# Why is it that wcout << ""; is OK but wcout << string(); is not?

Tags: string, encoding, iostream, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wcout << L"Hello";          // OK.
    wcout << wstring(L"Hello"); // OK.
    wcout << "Hello";           // OK. Why?
    wcout << string("Hello");   // Error. Why?
}
```

Why does `std::wcout` accept a narrow string literal as its argument but doesn't accept a narrow string object?

Comment: `error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::wcout << std::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"Hello"), (*(const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>())))'`?

Comment: +1 I've been puzzled by this IOStream weirdness too.

Comment: why? coz stone cold said so! that's why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is dictated by § 27.7.3.6.4 of the C++11 Standard, where the following two overloaded operators (among others) are specified:

```
template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(
    basic_ostream<charT,traits>& out, 
    const charT* s
    );

template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(
    basic_ostream<charT,traits>& out, 
    const char* s
    );
```

The last overload deals explicitly with `char`-based C-strings. This means that even for instantiations of the `basic_ostream<>` class template with the argument `wchar_t` there will be one overload which will deal with narrow `char` strings.

Moreover, per § 27.7.3.6.4/5:

> Padding is determined as described in 22.4.2.2.2. **The n characters starting at s are widened using out.widen (27.5.5.3). The widened characters and any required padding are inserted into out**. Calls width(0).

---

On the other hand, the statement `wcout << string("Hello");` does not compile because `string` does not have an implicit conversion to `const char*`, and because there is no overload of `operator <<` that would insert a `string` built with one character type into an output stream with a different underlying character type.

In Standard terms (see § 21.4.8.9), here is how the definition of the overloaded `operator <<` looks like for `std::string`:

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(
    basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os,
    const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& str
    );
```

As you can see, the same template parameter `charT` is used to instantiate both `basic_ostream` and `basic_string`.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, I'm guessing [this overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is used:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os, 
                                         const char* s );
```

Where `wstream` is essentially a `basic_ostream<wchar_t>`.

For why `string("Hello")` doesn't work, it's simply because there is no conversion from `string` to `wstring`, nor an overload of `operator<<` provided.

Comment: Huh, funny. I assumed the second parameter would be `const CharT *` only.

Comment: is *it's simply because there is no conversion from wstring to string* a typo?  should it be *it's simply because there is no conversion from string to wstring*?