# boost::variant can not handle string and wstring together

Tags: c++, wstring, boost-variant

While attempting to add support for UTF-8 locales in a library, I added
the type `std::wstring` to the `boost::variant` that holds a value.

At that point, I start to get errors with something down inside `boost::variant`:

```
Blockquote/opt/TWWfsw/libboost147/include/boost/variant/detail/variant_io.hpp: In member function 'void boost::detail::variant::printer<OStream>::operator()(const T&) const [with T = std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >, OStream = std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >]':<BR>
/opt/TWWfsw/libboost147/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:858:   instantiated from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::internal_visit(T&, int) [with T = const std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >, Visitor = boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >]'<BR>
< SNIP SNIP ><BR>
Cursor.H:84:   instantiated from here
/opt/TWWfsw/libboost147/include/boost/variant/detail/variant_io.hpp:64: error: no match for 'operator<<' in '((const boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >*)this)->boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::out_ << operand'<BR>
/opt/TWWfsw/gcc44/include/c++/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]<BR>etc.
```

This example is using boost-1.47 w/ g++ 4.4.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#define NO_STRING 1

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
#if defined(NO_STRING)
  boost::variant<int, std::wstring> v;
#else
  boost::variant<int, std::wstring, std::string> v;
#endif
  v = 3;
  std::wcout << v << std::endl;
  std::wstring T(L"wide char literal");
  v = T;
  std::wcout << v << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This program will output:

> 3
> wide char literal

but if the `#define` is removed, and both `string` and `wstring` are in the variant template parameters, the same error results.

My question is, can I create something that will satisfy this missing definition, like a template specialization?

Perhaps defining a variant visitor that converts the wide string to a narrow string? (not a general solution, but narrowing would work in my case)

The problem comes from using `<<` with the variant when both strings are defined.  Even if I only output the int through the variant, it won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is not `boost::variant` can't handle both `string` and `wstring`. The problem is that `wcout` cannot handle `std::string`. For more info about this, see [Why is it that wcout << ""; is OK but wcout << string(); is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696997/why-is-it-that-wcout-is-ok-but-wcout-string-is-not)

Comment: So even though the variant doesn't contain a std::string value, it can't be used in "wcout <<".  Conversely, that would also mean it could not be used in "cout <<" or any stream insertion operation.  Doesn't that *severely* limit boost::variant's usefulness?   Essentially I have to have applications where all strings are wide, or all strings are narrow.

Comment: It's not that using "wcout" is the problem, if I modify the program to use std::cout and output the int-valued variant, the the same error occurs.

Comment: John - your answer is a valid one - but it just isn't what this question is about.  The problem is with the implementation of boost::variant, it can't seem to deal with "operator<<" in cases where wide and narrow strings are valid types.  In fact, the program compiles & runs if we remove calls to operator<< and fails when only calls to operator<<(int) are actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer by @John Bandela: He is actually reight. I'll just explain a bit more about the culprit.

Notice that `std::cout << std::string()` and `std::wcout << std::wstring()` are valid while `std::wcout << std::string()` and `std::wcout << std::string()` are not. This is simply due to the definition of the stream operator (see [Why is it that wcout << ""; is OK but wcout << string(); is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696997/why-is-it-that-wcout-is-ok-but-wcout-string-is-not)) It is simply not possible unless you provide an overload that handles this.

The same applies to variants: If you try to stream a `variant<std::string>` into `std::wcout` or a `variant<std::wstring>` into `std::cout` you will get the same error.

The bottom of your problem is: The operation you apply to the variant (visit, stream-operator) has to support all possibly contained types. That is due to the implementation which is like (pseudo-code):

```
void variant::visit(T operation){
  if(contained is T1) operation(static_cast<T1>(contained));
  else if(contained is T2) operation(static_cast<T2>(contained));
  ...
}
```

So a solution to your problem would be: Implement the operation yourself for all types:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

std::wstring stringToWString(const std::string& v){
    // Only works for single-byte strings. Do it better!
    std::wstring result(v.begin(), v.end());
    return result;
}

struct visitor: boost::static_visitor<void>{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(const T& v) const { std::wcout << v; }
    void operator()(const std::string& v) const { std::wcout << stringToWString(v); }
};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  boost::variant<int, std::wstring, std::string> v;
  v = 3;
  boost::apply_visitor(visitor(), v);
  std::wcout << std::endl;
  std::wstring T(L"wide char literal");
  v = T;
  boost::apply_visitor(visitor(), v);
  std::wcout << std::endl;
  v = std::string("Narrow string");
  boost::apply_visitor(visitor(), v);
  std::wcout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35e156f38208af1e

**Final Note: Do not support UTF-8 by using `std::wstring`!** UTF-8 can be stored in a regular `std::string`. There are very(!) few places where you want to convert this to anything else. One of them is dealing with WinAPI. For that you can write wrappers, that accept a `std::string` and convert right before passing it to the actual API.

So general advice: Use UTF-8 (in `std::string`) everywhere in your program and only convert at border points.

Comment: Since I asked this question I've learned more about encoding and now I'm a zealot for UTF-8 everywyere.  If you're interested, read http://utf8everywhere.org