# fail to wcout wchar[] which from GetWindowText();

Tags: c++, winapi

```
while(TRUE){
    HWND window = GetForegroundWindow();
    WCHAR str[300] ;
    ZeroMemory(str, sizeof(str));
    GetWindowTextW(window,str,299);
    wcout<<L"11"<<endl;
    wcout<<str;
    wcout<<L"22"<<endl;
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

this code will output "11",and then stuck. When I try to use `char` ， `cout` and `GetWindowTextA`,this loop can run and  output English  character normal.
With single step  debug, the loop still run actually. But don't output anything. And `str` show window's title normal.

Comment: did you check the return value or `GetLastError()`?

Comment: This is probably a problem with the console getting stuck on certain characters

Comment: always check return values from functions. e.g. is `window` valid?

Comment: I am surprised this code compile, you are using char string literal with `wcout`, you should replace `"11"` and `"22"` by `L"11"` and `L"22"`.

Comment: @Sedenion see https://stackoverflow.com/q/14696997/10622916

Comment: Did you consider single-stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @Sedenion I have change it to L"11",but it can't run  still.

Comment: I suggest you check the numerical value of the two or three first characters of `str` after call to `GetWindowTextW`, this might be what "kill" your output.

Comment: The English output is normal. Stuck when another language appears? Have tried setting a locale for wcout. `locale loc(""); wcout.imbue(loc);` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/locale-class?view=msvc-170#example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK ! Just need to set `locale` that I forget.

```
wcout.imbue(locale("your locale"));
```